# Why python show 'In:' after import my own module

Tags: python, python-3.5

I tried to import my own module in Python 3.5. Before import I add the path into sys.path, but there is still 'In:'. What should I input after 'In'? I have tried input the path, but it was not work.

[image]

Here is the code of my module. It is a simple test, and I just wanted to learn how to import own module in Python.

```
import ipdb
'list mulitiple'
def prod(l):
    length = len(l)
    if length == 1:
        return l[1]
    else:
        result = 1
        for i in l:
            result *= i
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    print(prod(l))
```

It's will be so sweet for you to also help me to add pythonpath permanently. I have changed 'pythonpath' in systempath, but it seems not right...

Comment: If `length` is 1, I think you meant to say `return l[0]`.

Comment: Oh,yes. Thank you for pointing out that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module was imported.  But code in the `if __name__=="__main__"` block doesn't run when your module is imported, only when you run the module directly.  (That's the purpose of the `if __name__=="__main__"` block.)  So importing your module didn't do anything obvious; it loaded your function but didn't call it.

Since it looks like you're using IPython, you could use the `%run` magic command to run your file as described [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/tutorial.html).

If you're working interactively, often you'd rather just import your file and then use it from the interactive shell.  For instance, after importing it, you can now do `mymath.prod([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])` to call your function, just as you would with any ordinary library module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I solved it by commenting the code about IPython.